# jQuery delegate with two element selectors

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm trying to disable a function attached to a hover event if my site is viewed on a touch device. If the device is touch then my body tag has '.touch' and if there's no touch it has '.no-touch'

When I write the delegate function like this with the touch class

```
$('.no-touch .list').delegate('img', 'hover', function() {
...
}
```

It stops working even though I'm not on a touch device. Also, in Chrome Developer Tools when I look in Elements the body tag has the touch class on it, in the Source view the body tag doesn't have the class. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: `$('.no-touch , .list')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you assign a delegated handler to some a selector that finds the body tag it is not sufficient to change the body's class in order to remove it from that handler.  You must either:

1. undelegate the body tag -- regardless of what it's current selector is
2. inspect it's class in the handler. When it is fired and take different logical branches depending upon which class it has

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/j6kXX/)

```
$('whateverSelectorIsRelevantNow').undelegate('img', 'hover', function() {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.no-touch,  .list').delegate('img', 'hover', function() {
...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this target both selectors? I'm trying to only have the function trigger if .list is inside a body element with .no-touch